# Is there enough evidence to conclude Hans is a fake brave?

Tags: rokka-no-yuusha

Hans initially accused Adlet of being the fake to escape suspicion.

Then when Adlet returned, he deliberately let him live in order to maintain his alibi. Because of this, Adlet no longer suspected Hans, which worked out according to his plan.

However, Nachetanya still suspected Hans, and pointed out his inconsistencies. Is it safe to say Hans is a fake brave or at least a potential fake brave? Is there any evidence proving his innocence?

Comment: I'm currently on the fifth volume of Rokka no Yuusha. It seems like Hans is likely to be a fake based on the story clues while Chamot is possibly a fake, but highly unlikely.

Comment: Usually in this kind of series, the one that is most unlikely is the one that is fake. Remember Ichimaru Gin from Bleach and Enoshima Junko from Danganronpa? Gin is actually aiming to kill Aizen (the main evil) while Junko who was presumably dead, actually faked her death and is the main antagonist. Using the same logic, Hans might actually be a real brave.

Comment: @SakuraiTomoko Hmm who are the most unlikely people? Adlet and Maura?

Comment: I'd say Adlet is out since he is the main protagonist and his background story has already been laid out. Gin and Junko didn't have his background story laid out until near the end. I personally suspected Maura, though I have no proof whatsoever.

Comment: I'd say Adlet is in the mix specifically *because* he's the main protagonist; he's the only one with any real 'plot asymmetry', any meta-reason that it should be him and not someone else. He also seems to have gotten 'demon-touched' quite distinctly while in jail in the first episode. This is not to suggest that Adlet _knows_ he's the fake, but he's still my leading candidate for actually being the fake (though caveat: I'm presently an ep behind).

Comment: I would go with Maura. Everyone is trying to find out how could someone get in without breaking the seal, but everyone is ignoring that Maura has the key... Sorry, I don't have enough points to add as a comment...

Comment: My guess for the fake would be Nachetanya. Since Adlet is the main char I'm sure he can't be the fake. Hans is equal to Adlet in terms of skill, so he would make a suitable hero himself. then there's Maura and Chamot, Since Chamot is the strongest Saint she seems a legit hero and with Maura overseeing her, she must have alot of skill herself since Chamot respects her enough to obey her. Flamie has been nothing but honest so far and her skill seems pretty high. That just leaves goldof and Nachetanya for me. Nahctanya herself said Goldov is stronger than her tho.. so that leaves her as the fake.

Comment: @ChenOrihara Also recall that Nachetanya was trying to protect Adlet. Assuming that the fake's goal is to kill multiple braves, she wouldn't want Adlet to die alone, or else it will prove he wasn't a fake after he died :) I'm applying this same reasoning to Hans, which indicates he is potentially a fake.

Comment: You have to cite an episode in order to limit the scope of the question. otherwise, since this is an airing series, the possible answers could change in validity.

Comment: @Mindwin Citing an episode might possibly be spoiling the series, which I have been trying to avoid. Right now, I'm just looking for evidence that disproves the possibility of Hans being a fake brave by logical contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Spoilers ahead, read if you really want to know. I came to Japan for a business trip last week. So, I went and bought all 6 volumes of Rokka no Yusha and started reading though them while slacking on the job, starting Volume 6 today. Therefore, this time, I will put in a brief explanation of each volume and prove each Brave's innocence one by one, then prove Adlet is guilty and Hans is innocent. However, the assumption is that there is only one fake in the Seven existing now.

**Volume 1: Nashetania Arc**

> Watch the anime.

**Volume 2: Mora's Daughter Arc** (Not really called this but I cannot think of a better name)

> In this volume, it is revealed that [Tgurneu](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Tgurneu) has held [Mora](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Mora_Chester)'s daughter hostage through getting one of his Kyoma minions which is a parasitic worm to build a nest in Shenilla's chest. Through a letter he forged with the Saint of Medicine, [Toulo Maynes](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Toulo_Maynes)'s handwriting, he invited Mora to an alley to discuss the conditions for Shenilla's release. Mora brought along the Saint of Words, [Marmanna Keynes](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Marmanna_Keynes) and also called out to the Saint of Salt, [Weylynn Coteau](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Weylynn_Coteau), but she did not make it in time. Without Weylynn, the two saints and Tgurneu started the discussion. In the end, they made deals which cannot be overturned as Marmanna's powers forced them to follow the contract or they die. The important deals are as follow:
>
> - Tgurneu was to never lie to Mora or he would die.
> - Tgurneu would command the worm in Shenilla's chest to commit suicide if he was killed or Mora killed one of the other Braves.
> - If Mora died before she killed another brave or if Tgurneu did not die at the same time, Shenilla would die.
>
> These deals forced Mora to undergo severe training and implanting a Volcano crystal in her chest as the last resort to kill Tgurneu. She also trained [Rolonia Manchetta](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Rolonia_Manchetta), the Saint of Fresh Blood to be able to revive the dead by letting her test her abilities of blood control on Mora as she was implanted with the crystal. Then they tested her abilities to revive someone on a dying old man. This is Mora's Plan B, where she would kill a Brave, then revive him again.
>
> A lot of things happened and Tgurneu, while using the body of the three-winged Kyoma, told a lie to Mora, saying she was the seventh Brave. Tgurneu then escaped through Mora's barrier in a jellyfish Kyoma in order to hide that his host had died due to the lie. This lie caused Mora to switch to Plan B as she believed she was the seventh. Mora knocked out [Fremy](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Fremy_Speeddraw) and [Chamo](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Chamo_Rosso) and his them in the cave in the barrier of the [Saint of the Single Flower](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Saint_of_the_Single_Flower). She then used her power of echo to call for Adlet and Rolonia to head to the cave and asked Goldof and Hans to chase after Fremy, whom she lied that Fremy ran away leading them to a group of Kyoma under her command sent by Tgurneu.However, Hans went instead of Adlet as he saw through Mora's plans. Then, Hans and Mora fought, Mora slit Hans's throat with his knife, killing him. Then she asked Rolonia to revive him as she had trained her.
>
> When Hans died, Adlet realised a petal disappeared from his hand, this is the piece of evidence that proves Hans's innocence. Later, Adlet also proved Mora's innocence by proving that Tgurneu was merely using the three-winged Kyoma as a host and only the host died due to the lie. The point is if Mora was fake, the host would have lived. Adlet also revealed Tgurneu was a fig-like Kyouma as his spray had revealed through spraying it on a piece of the fig fruit that the host ate in their encounter when they all entered the [Wailing Demon Territory](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Wailing_Demon_Territory). Furthermore, the author revealed this to us by saying Tgurneu was in a new host in front of the corpse of the three-winged Kyoma.
>
> Therefore, in this volume, Mora and Hans were proven innocent.

**Volume 3: Nashetania's arm loss arc** (Also not really called this but I think its funny)

> In this volume, we will prove Goldof and Chamo are real Braves. In this arc, Tgurneu and Dozzu have cooperated in order to kill off Chamo. In truth, it was a plan by Nashetania to use Tgurneu to save themselves from Cargikk, then use the Braves to then save themselves again from Tgurneu. Of course, Tgurneu betrayed them. They did so by getting Nashetania to activate the Blade Gem she implanted in Chamo's stomach though the use of Dozzu during a duel they had a few years back. Goldof's helmet, which is a [Sacred Instrument](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Sacred_Instrument), known as the Helmet of Truth, created by a Saint of Words activated as Nashetania was captured by Tgurneu and held captive in Dark Specialist No. 26's stomach, hidden in a lava area within a 1km radius of Chamo in order to keep the Blade Gem activated. Nashetania got her left arm amputated by Tgurneu in order to attach it to a monkey Kyoma to leak her blood to deceive the Braves into thinking they are chasing the real Nashetania as he tries to buy time until 3 hours passes in order to kill Chamo with the Blade Gem. Goldof hears Nashetania's cries for help and heads to rescue her whilst the other Braves try to kill him as they now think he is possibly the seventh. However, Tgurneu, in a new body, approaches Adlet, Rolonia and Fremy to ask for a truce and cooperate until Nashetania is killed. Of course, they questioned him and tried to kill him after they got information out of him. In this conversation, he claimed that Goldof is not his seventh Brave as his Brave is trying to save Chamo, not Nashetania.
>
> Not important stuff occured and Goldof found out Nashetania was held captive by Tgurneu after Dozzu hinted to him of No. 26's ability, which is similar to Nashetania's hiding ability. He found her in the lava area and stole a Saint's needle from Adlet and used it to kill No. 26 to save Nashetania during the scuffle with Adlet, Rolonia and Fremy at the lava area.
>
> Important things to take away:
>
> - Tgurneu made a deal with Dozzu to respectively not harm Nashetania and Fremy.
> - Goldof is a real Brave as Tgurneu was toying with him and even told him tons of truth such as the deal Cargikk, Dozzu and him made 200 years ago.
> - Chamo is a real brave as both Dozzu and Tgurneu tried to get rid of her and they were clearly trying.

**Volume 4: Fremy's mother is an ant arc** (I cannot stop laughing about this.)

> [Raina Milan](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Raina), Adlet's best friend is the main character of this arc, though Rolonia is also proven innocent in this arc. Most of the details about this arc can be obtained by reading Raina and [Nia Grasta](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Nia_Grasta)'s character biography on the wikia. Therefore, the important point is that Rolonia, Hans and Adlet learnt Fremy was the Black Barren Flower and Adlet kept this fact from the other Braves until the next volume and only revealed the existence of the Sacred Instrument and its functions. Rolonia proved her innocence by really trying to save the corpse soldiers and nearly died due to her naivety. In the final chapter of this volume, it was revealed that Fremy's mother was an ant and was ordered to raise Fremy with love, but it ended up really loving Fremy and continued raising Fremy's dog, waiting for Fremy's return. This contradicts what Fremy said in the first volume but this is cleared up in the fifth volume so I will explain it later. Not much to take away in this volume so I will just move on to Volume 5.

**Volume 5: Adlet is fake arc.**

> In this volume, they explore the Temple of Fate that was built by Tgurneu, here they discover the functions of the Black Barren Flower through deciphering the Holy Words carved onto the floor around the mummified body of the Saint of the Single Flower. Here is where they discover that the Crest of the seventh was created using the powers of the Saint of the Single Flower and hence would mean killing the seventh may prove disastrous. Fremy also figured out she is the Black Barren Flower by remembering that she went into the temple and saw the Saint of the Single Flower before. This led to a split between the Braves, where Adlet wanted to keep Fremy alive while the rest wanted her dead, even Fremy wished to commit suicide. This caused Adlet to cooperate Dark Specialist No. 30, who also thought Adlet was the seventh as he was the only one trying to protect Fremy, who would drive them all to death by draining the powers of the Crests. He ordered No. 30 to try and kill Fremy with full force and to swallow a Light Gem that has a secondary functions and find a way to get it to the other Braves somehow, like vomiting it out after being hit or get himself cut up. This is due to him telling a lie that he saw a message to not kill Fremy in one of the rooms in the temple. Of course, Hans saw through the lie when Adlet told it and started the chase in the temple a few chapters ago. The point is that Adlet managed to trick Mora, Nashetania, Rolonia and Fremy into believing Hans was the seventh and it was unwise to kill Fremy to stop the Black Barren Flower as it has a more disastrous secondary function if Fremy was killed. Hans and Chamo split from the other as they believed that Adlet was fake. Goldof also believed so but stayed behind to protect Nashetania.
>
> In the last chapter, a flashback to a chat between the three-winged Kyoma and Tgurneu revealed Adlet was the fake and Tgurneu had the power to incite love in someone. Tgurneu used this power to cause the Saint of the Single Flower to fall in love with him, persuading her to give the seventh Crest to him to be given to Adlet. He also used this power to make Adlet fall in love with Fremy in order to ensure he would protect her at all costs. This is due to his belief of, wait for it "LOVE IS THE MOST POWERFUL THING THERE IS!".

**Volume 6: Tgurneu's death arc**

> In this arc, Adlet discovers he is fake through Tgurneu taking out a petal from his body. This petal contains a message from the Saint of the Single Flower which is played to Adlet through his Crest despite Tgurneu being 2km away from his location. Only a part of the message was played but it goes like this: "Warrior of a thousands years from now, I hereby bestow you the Seventh Crest to...". Tgurneu only allowed the message to be played up until here. Through this, Adlet himself realised he was the seventh. Fremy also became a hostage of Tgurneu through him activating a tumour implanted in her chest. This tumour is special in that if Tgurneu was killed, Fremy dies too, he activated it from a distance by stabbing himself with his own vine. He also relayed a message to Adlet, saying that unless he killed the other Braves, the one he loves will die. After this, he switched his plans to help Tgurneu kill everyone but Fremy. He also wanted her to return to the Kyoma since the army have been shouting for Fremy to go back to them.
>
> Chamo and Hans appeared in Chapter 3 to stop the Braves. Here, Hans enacts his plan of pretending he was the seventh to lure out Adlet to negotiate a deal with him as he guessed that Adlet was doing everything to protect Fremy and not really on Tgurneu's side. Chamo was unaware of the plans and Hans also stole Chamo's surveillance Juuma in order to use it later. He wounds Chamo in order to pretend he was the seventh and throws knives at Adlet, these knives had messaged written on them to lure Adlet away from the others using a lie that he can kill Fremy through using Chamo. His plan after disabling Adlet and questioning him is: Adlet will lie to Tgurneu that Hans has been neutralised, then tell Tgurneu a fake plan as a cover for his real plan to kill Tgurneu, this plan was the plan that Adlet came up with in Chapter 1, which was to set the forest on fire and get a cheetah Kyouma to report back to Tgurneu after Dark specialist 24, which is what I would like to call "The Telephone Kyouma" has been eliminated, thus leading the Braves to him. But, instead of killing Tgurneu, now they will capture him, thus preventing Fremy's death due to Tgurneu's death. Then, out of the blue, Tgurneu appeared as Adlet was deciding whether to use Hans's plan, using the Book of truth to discover that Hans was lying about being able to kill Fremy.
>
> In Chapter 4, we discover that Tgurneu desires, he craves to see people in pain because of love. His lust for this has pushed him to create the perfect pair to see these emotions on people's faces. The pair being: the girl that wishes to be loved, Fremy. The boy that has an unbreakable heart to love her, Adlet. Due to his greed to see these emotions, he did not want to come up with more effective strategies to kill the Braves, but just wanted to see Fremy and Adlet suffer. This chapter really is just Tgurneu sadistically torturing Adlet by telling him the reason that he loves Fremy is because of him loving inducing powers, not out of his own heart. Adlet despairs after hearing this and despite Hans's pleas towards him while Hans himself was getting chased around by 40 Kyouma, he was unresponsive Hans also lost his Juuma that he wanted to release to call for Chamo's help (it got stabbed by Adlet's needle and was then tied up by Tgurneu). Fremy, on the other hand enacted a plan to get rid of the tumour in her chest. She would pretend to betray the Braves and purposely get her heart gouged out by Rolonia so that Dark Specialist 14 would heal her, thus ridding her of the tumour. But of course, 14 knows about the tumour and he believes that it cannot be simply 'healed away' as it integrates with the cellular structure of the host. The twist is, Fremy's mother evolved in a way that allowed her to rid Fremy of the tumour after her heart was regenerated. This was done by always rubbing Fremy's chest when she raised her. Adlet, however, was an idiot, after he heard Fremy's fake betrayal through 24, he believed it and told Tgurneu the real plans. Bright side: he found out Fremy loves him. Dark side: he fell into despair after learning that even Atro Spiker was manipulated by him, to groom Adlet into the strongest man to protect Fremy. This causes Adlet to enter an unresponsive state and want to be killed as he had betrayed everyone.
>
> Chapter 5, Dark Specialist 13 uses his [Poison Gas](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Poison_Gas_(move)) attack (**pokemon reference by me**). He produced toxins that was washed into the underground drainage system of the ruins and used his 'little babies' to vaporise the water and unleash the gas onto above ground. Adlet was swallowed by a Hippopotamus Kyouma so that later, Tgurneu can release control over him and get him to kill Fremy, for him to achieve a higher form of ecstasy by looking at the despair that Fremy will display for him. In order to counter the poison gas, Mora collapses the ground below her, killing 13. After regaining his will to fight though the message:"I will definitely make you happy!" engraved on a gunpowder lattice given to him by Fremy, Adlet punched his way out of the Kyouma's stomach and heard Mora's echo message of Fremy has been saved. He looks at Tgurneu and intends to kill Tgurneu after knowing that Fremy will no longer be bound to him. He thought: "Dawn is coming, when the sun rises, **One shall stand. One shall fall**." *That is obviously not what the book said, but it is what it intended to say.*
>
> Chapter 6, Adlet and Hans cooperate and try their best to not get mauled by the Kyouma. Chamo senses something is amiss and discovers one of the message knives Hans threw to Adlet in Chapter 3, and managed to reason that Hans did not really try to kill her when he wounded her. Mora and Goldof are trying to regroup on the battlefield after Mora exhausted herself to kill 13. Rolonia and Nashetania held off the Kyouma while Fremy headed to Adlet. In this battle in some ruins, Adlet, Chamo, Fremy, Hans, Dozzu face off against Tgurneu and Dark Specialist 1, the Kyouma that is made up of forty Kyoumas and 1 leader bird-type Kyouma that Tgurneu inhabited. This Kyouma is the strongest Dark Specialist as it practically allowed Tgurneu to be in 40 places at once and coordinate the perfect attacks. After a game of cat and mouse, Adlet figured out that Tgurneu was controlling all the Kyouma they were battling simultaneously. Thus, he tricked Tgurneu into looking at him by confessing his love to Fremy as he realised that vision is not shared by the Kyouma despite them being controlled by Tgurneu. Adlet charged at Tgurneu but got impaled by Tgurneu. However, he instead spit his blood into 1's mouth, this caused 1 to drop to the ground and roll in pain. Adlet had stabbed himself with the Saint's needle and made his blood poisonous to Kyouma. Fremy shot 1 and forced Tgurneu out of 1. Adlet grabbed Tgurneu while his underlings tried to save him. Adlet was saddened that the thing that groomed him to be the Strongest in the World was such a pitiful existence and said: "I am not your toy as you had claimed! You existed for me. In order for me to meet Fremy, you were let to live by me!" Tgurneu, who believed that love was meant to be trampled by him, desperately wanted to reject the fact that he was defeated by Adlet's love, wanted to mentally wound Adlet and Fremy before Adlet killed him. He used the Book of Truth on himself and said to Fremy: "Your mother truly loved you!". To Adlet he whispered: "Your sister was killed by Fremy.". After Adlet killed Tgurneu, six shots of light flew out of Fremy's crest, one landing each on Chamo, Hans, Mora, Rolonia, Nashetania, Goldof. Only Adlet did not receive this as his seventh crest is very special and did not have its power stolen by the Black Barren Flower, unlike Nashetania's crest, which is a real crest but from the 2nd generation. Adlet passed out after killing Tgurneu and woke up later with the Braves discussing what to do with him as they now have to face Cargikk, who was originally oppressed by Tgurneu and did not attack them. Adlet, released from Tgurneu's control, no longer loved Fremy and returned to the man that wanted revenge on the Kyouma and nothing else.
>
> Epilogue: Cargikk wanders through the burnt forest that the Braves faced Tgurneu's army. He roared in despair and apologised to his fallen comrades, expressing his regret in not being able to save them. Meanwhile, the mummified body of the Saint of the Single Flower is released from her chains, presumably by her own powers as the chains just came undone without being touched. She teleported to the roof of the Temple of Fate from Volume 5 and get carried away by a bird Kyouma. She got carried to the Majin, a mud puddle. The mud puddle sprouted tentacles and devoured the Kyouma and slowly dragged the Saint of the Single Flower into itself. As it dragged the Saint, it grew beautiful lips and gratefully said Maon, do not worry, Adlet will bring the Seventh crest made for me and save me. Maon is the name of the Saint.

Finally all done, to be honest this is not a very good series. I originally bought and read it just to prove to krikara that Adlet was the fake and Hans was a real Brave. After proving that, I had lost all drive to finish Volume 6. However, to my surprise, Volume 6 was the best of all 6 volumes and I may consider buying Volume 7 when it is released. Overall rating 5/10, passable read.

Comment: @Michael McQuade Thank you for that edit and also thanks for showing me how to do the thing to block out spoilers.

Comment: Not a problem! If you want to read more about that you can check out: http://anime.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Which volume is your very last statement from?

Comment: There is a flaw in your answer though. No one knows how the crest responds to a fake brave as stated in novel and here http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Crest_of_Six_Flowers. So we must prove the answer. Can you provide more explanation behind your fake brave?

Comment: Due do Adlet having not died yet, there is actually no way of telling how it would respond as the wikia says. The only thing we know is that Tgurneu created the crest from the Saint's powers and Adlet is a fake. But it would be safe to assume that since it is still a fake crest, a petal would not disappear. However, your question is whether Hans is fake and I think I have fully answered that by proving he is a real Brave.

Comment: I read the novels and I don't see where it says Adlet is a fake brave. Wiki says it right at the top of Adlet's page, but then gives no more information regarding that matter. I guess I'm looking for more of an explanation about how Adlet is fake because nothing has indicated that yet.

Comment: Then maybe it would be more adequate to modify your question to whether Adlet is the fake Brave or ask a new question about Adlet since right now you are asking about Hans.

Comment: Okay I'm currently caught up with the latest volume. Both supporting claims from your answer are wrong. It seems like the Wiki contains misleading information. If we assume Adlet is a fake brave, then yes, we can say by default Hans is not a fake, however, there is nothing indicating Adlet is indeed a fake.

Comment: Like I said before, you are talking about Hans, not Adlet. Thus, there is no point in proving that Adlet is real since there are still other braves that may be fake. Therefore, I believe the answer to your question is not about proving Adlet's innocence, but instead Hans's.

Comment: The question asked if there was enough evidence to prove Hans is a fake brave. All your evidence is wrong.Therefore you have not proved Hans' innocence.

Comment: @krikara , are you happy with this explanation and answer now?

Comment: @AstralSea You've got the different volumes in block quotes: is this your own information or did you cite it from somewhere? If it is your own I think it would look better if we made each section a header using `#` and then separated the sections with lines `---`.

Comment: @u人ʘ‿‿ ʘ人u Thanks for that, totally forgot about updating this after I finished the book a few months back. I guess I procrastinated until memory loss.

Comment: @u人ʘ‿‿ ʘ人u Thanks for your advice on formatting, I have bolded the titles, hope that makes it easier to read, Feel free to edit it if the format displeases you. Thanks for helping me find a way to spend my boring holiday by reminding me of this.

Comment: @krikara I have finished the summary for Volume 6, now I hope that you are truly satisfied knowing that Hans was a real Brave and Adlet is the fake.

Answer (score 1):

In light of the recently aired anime episode it's easy to say that the 7th brave is:

> Nachetanya. Her objective is to have humans and fiends live together in a state of absolute peace.

More info can be found in either the first volume of the light novels, or on the [wikia](http://rokkanoyuusha.wikia.com/wiki/Nashetania_Loei_Piena_Augustra)

Comment: Your facts in your answer are correct, however it does not answer the question. Also, the finale revealed something new, which makes the question relevant.